# Comparing "atom bomb" & "atomic bomb" with "atom explosion" & "atomic explosion"

Tags: difference, meaning, adjectives

Merriam Webster says that "atom" is a noun, not an adjective, albeit there is the entry "atom bomb" in which, I think, "atom" is used as an adjective.

Google Books has a lot of hits for "atom explosion". For example, in the Bulletin of the Atomic Scientists it is written:

> Then the aerial bomb, to strike by the thousands, followed by the **atom explosion** to reach the hundreds of thousands.

So, while in the name of that bulletin the scientists are "atomic", in an its quote the "explosion" is "atom".

When can we use "atom" in adjectival form? Are there differences in meaning between "atom explosion" and "atomic explosion"?
If "atom explosion" means "explosion of the atom", why aren't "fusion" or "fission" used, rather than "explosion"?

Comment: The Bulletin of Atomic Scientists is a specialist publication for specialists.  I interpret the two expressions "atom explosion" and "atomic explosion" to mean the same thing in this context -- variations in technical jargon.  The quote doesn't sound to me like it was written by a native English speaker.

Comment: *Atom* in *atom bomb* can be described as an [attributive noun](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attributive_noun).

Comment: @barbara beeton: Wikipedia says [The Bulletin of Atomic Scientists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulletin_of_the_Atomic_Scientists) is a **nontechnical online magazine**. But I agree, the  phrasing of OP's citation doesn't strike me as likely to be from a competent native speaker. Come to that, I'm doubtful many professional scientists would express the sentiment at all - it's a bit "populist tub-thumping".

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- Thanks for correction on content level of the publication.  (It still sounds like technical jargon, or maybe better in this case, pseudo-technical jargon.  "Populist tub-thumping" has a nice ring to it though.)

Comment: @barbara: Well, you have to admit that saying things like *aeriel (presumably, "conventional") bombs strike by the thousands, atom bombs reach the hundreds of thousands* is seriously loaded/emotive phrasing even if it's wrapped up in "pseudo-technical jargon". As it happens, I was discussing the Hiroshima/Nagasaki bombs a couple of days ago with my father. If they *hadn't* been dropped, he'd have been shipped off to the Far East when WW2 ended in Europe; most enlisted men at the time were shitting themselves at the prospect of being sent off to near-certain death there...

Comment: ...the general consensus was that more lives were saved than lost by the dropping of those bombs, but that's not normally the way later generations see it. They just assume we're all somehow at the mercy of "mad scientists" who make bombs because they like the idea of killing people. The truth is it's our *leaders* who create the conditions of war, and it's *we the people collectively* who elect (or at least, *tolerate*) our leaders, and encourage them to act the way they do.

Answer (score 3):

In English nouns are sometimes used as adjectives rather than using an adjective form of the noun. For example, we routinely say "tin can" and not "tin's can" or "tinny can", "dog show" rather than "dogs' show" or "canine show", "California beaches" rather than "Californian beaches", etc etc.

The catch is that there's no simple rule saying when you can use a noun as an adjective. You pretty much have to learn them case by case.

"Atom bomb" and "atomic bomb" are, to the best of my knowledge, exact synonyms.

I have never heard anyone say "atom explosion". It's always "atomic explosion". Google Ngrams -- http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=atom+explosion%2Catomic+explosion&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share= -- shows essentially zero use of "atom explosion". Whatever uses you found, maybe they are using the phrase to mean something different. If not they're being very unconventional.

Answer (score 3):

*Atomic* is an adjective.
*Atom* is a noun.
If you said

> The instrument measured the **atom explosion** in the **atom smasher**.

*explosion* and *smasher* are nouns and *atom* is a noun modifier. It means actual atom(s) were acted on. I suppose it could be one or many atoms that exploded, but I think you would still say *atom*.

In the case of

> The instrument measured the **atomic** explosion.

this is referring to a type of explosion, and *atomic* is an adjective. This is the form generally used to describe atomic bombs and such that result from atomic reactions.

Answer (score 0):

> If "atom explosion" means "explosion of the atom", why aren't "fusion" or "fission" used, rather than "explosion"?

An explosion is always sudden and violent, while a fusion is a controlled process to get energy from atoms. What you get from a bomb is an explosion, whatever process is used to obtain it.

As for *atomic explosion* versus *atom explosion*, I think  the correct one is *atomic explosion*, since one of the meaning of *atomic* is, "related to the energy that is produced when atoms are split; related to weapons that use this energy." Since the explosion is caused from the energy produced from atoms when they are split, *atomic explosion* makes more sense to me.
*Atom* means, "the smallest part of a chemical element that can take part in a chemical reaction." *Atom bomb* is a set phrase; you can generally use *atom* to mean the energy generated when atoms are split, or weapons that use that energy.

Comment: Yes, but can we use *atom explosion* to refer to an *atomic explosion* in the same way we can use *atom bomb* to say *atomic bomb*? Plus, can a single *atom* explode in the same way a single *atom bomb* do?

Comment: Plus again, disintegration of a single atom is not known as "explosion" but, as far as I know, as ‎*annihilation*. However, as a civil engineer, I'm not sure of being right.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Normally we would use **nuclear explosion** or **atomic explosion**. *atom explosion* would be very unidiomatic.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Also degeneration of the atom would be called **fission**, not *annihilation* - that term is more normally used by atomic physicists for talking about anti-matter/matter collisions, which a nuclear reaction is not.